# 404 error with Apache rewrite and userdirs

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, http-status-code-404, mod-userdir

On my computer I have an Apache server with rewrite and userdir modules enabled.

The website is located in `/home/pedro/Dropbox/www/cocina/` and the webserver root is `/home/pedro/Dropbox/www/`

If go to `http://localhost/~pedro/cocina/index.php` the website shows ok.

In my `.htaccess` I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~pedro/cocina/
RewriteRule ^receta/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?receta=$1&desc=$2 [L,PT]
```

But when I try to open `http://localhost/~pedro/cocina/receta/1234/blabla.html` I get a 404 error (index.php not found).

Looking at `mod-rewrite` logs I can't see any problem:

```
rewrite 'receta/1234/blabla.html' -> '/index.php?receta=1234&desc=blabla'
forcing '/index.php' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
trying to replace prefix /home/pedro/Dropbox/www/cocina/ with /~pedro/cocina/
internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Where's the problem?

note: If I set up a v-host instead of using userdirs, the redirect works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this:

```
RewriteRule ^receta/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$  index.php?receta=$1&desc=$2 [L,PT]
```